Why can't I bind struct property of @Observable object inside of that object when I can do so outside of the object in SwiftUI?
When it comes to debouncing text fields I find just about every example does so in the view. And while this is ok I guess logically in my case it would be a better fit for the view model.
In theory the transition would be seamless however in this case I am trying to debounce a property of a struct that is inside of an @Observable object.
Here is my code
// For the purposes of this question this MUST be a struct
struct Review: Codable {
    var rating: Int = 1
    var body: String = ""
}

@MainActor
@Observable
class TestViewModel {
    var review: Review = Review()
    
    // Many other properties. Plain types, class types. etc.
    
    init() {
        // Cant do this here but would like to
        /*$review.body.debounce(for: .seconds(10), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { _ in
                print("It has been 10 seconds since this field was last edited")
            }*/
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Bindable var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $viewModel.review.body)
                .background(Color.gray)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

To me, what I do here TextEditor(text: $viewModel.review.body) is equivalent to $review.body.debounce(for: in the sense that both are trying to create a binding. The difference is SwiftUI is able to generate this binding whereas the version in the view model says Cannot find '$review' in scope. Using $self.viewModel also does not work.
I cannot label var review as @Published because I get Invalid redeclaration of synthesized property '_review'
I am guessing this in big part because Review is a structured so it is not Observable itself. But I also can't do this trick if I pull the var body: String out into TestViewModel
My guess is I fundamentally am not understanding the implications of my binding here TextEditor(text: $viewModel.review.body) perhaps this is relying on any change to the TestViewModel and thus becomes more costly as the properties in TestViewModel grow? Or maybe it's some SwiftUI magic making this work? I don't really get it.

You can get a Binding using @Bindable, but the properties in a @Observable class are not Combine publishers. You cannot debounce them even if you got a Binding.

You should use ObservableObject if you want Combine publishers.

withObservationTracking
